# How to display a image using PDF jqGridExport / Jqgrid?

Tags: jquery, pdf, jqgrid

Grid its ok, but **report doesn´t show images**.

I'm sure this question is common for users of jqgrid reports.

I've tried several different forms of settings and unfortunately with no success.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    var grid = $("#table_grid");
    var mydata = <?=json_encode(Yii::app()->controller->getSupportData($startDate, $endDate, $enterpriseCode));?>;


    grid.jqGrid({
        datatype: "local",
        data: mydata,
        colModel:[
            { label: '<?=Yii::t('customer', 'Customer');?>', name: 'EnterpriseName', width: 20, editable:true },
            { label: '<?=Yii::t('global', 'Responsible for Support');?>', name: 'Name', width: 15, editable:true },

            ......

            { label: '<?=Yii::t('global', 'Closed');?>', name: 'SupportClosed', width: 6, align:'center', formatter:

                function (SupportClosed) {
                    if (SupportClosed == 1)
                        return "<img src='http://dev-server/rma/images/icons/32x32/accept.png'/>";
                    else
                        return "<img src='http://dev-server/rma/images/icons/32x32/delete.png'/>";
                }},



        ],

        viewrecords: true,
        height: "100%",
        width: 1140,
        rowNum: 20,
        pager: '#jqGridPager',


    });

    $("#export").on("click", function(){
        $("#table_grid").jqGrid("exportToPdf",{
            title: "<?=Yii::t('global', 'Usage Report');?>",
            orientation: 'landscape',
            pageSize: 'A4',           
            customSettings: null,
            download: 'download',
            includeLabels : true,
            includeGroupHeader : true,
            includeFooter: true,
            fileName : "jqGridExport.pdf"
        })
    })

});
```

[Grid OK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lW7O.png)

[PDF - Report ERROR showing images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TO64y.png)

Answer (score 0):

At the moment this is limitation of the Guriddo jqGrid PDF Export. For more information when this will be available, please contact the support team of Guriddo jqGrid